# webkit_server Cannot find executable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webkit, capybara

I'm using Capybara to test my Rails app.

I need to test some javascript, so I've set up webkit to test those pages (don't remember all the steps, did it months ago).  Here is one such spec from months ago that works great:

```
describe "user fills in form", js: true, driver: :webkit do
...
end
```

This spec executes and passes just fine.

I made a new spec and have this spec:

```
describe "check player", js: true, driver: :webkit do
...
end
```

And I get this error:

```
2012-05-28 10:24:48.771 webkit_server[6274:207] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x104552dc0 </Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Unused> (not loaded)
2012-05-28 10:24:48.885 webkit_server[6274:207] Error loading /Applications/Amazon MP3 Downloader.app/Contents/Resources/AmazonMP3DownloaderPlugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AmazonMP3DownloaderPlugin:  dlopen(/Applications/Amazon MP3 Downloader.app/Contents/Resources/AmazonMP3DownloaderPlugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AmazonMP3DownloaderPlugin, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/Amazon MP3 Downloader.app/Contents/Resources/AmazonMP3DownloaderPlugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/AmazonMP3DownloaderPlugin: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
objc[6274]: Class WebCoreMovieObserver is implemented in both /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[6274]: Class WebCoreSharedBufferData is implemented in both /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[6274]: Class WebVideoFullscreenWindow is implemented in both /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[6274]: Class WebVideoFullscreenController is implemented in both /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[6274]: Class WebVideoFullscreenHUDWindowController is implemented in both /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[6274]: Class WebVideoFullscreenHUDWindow is implemented in both /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[6274]: Class WebWindowFadeAnimation is implemented in both /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[6274]: Class WebWindowScaleAnimation is implemented in both /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.0/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/QtWebKit and /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2012-05-28 10:24:48.981 webkit_server[6274:207] Error loading /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/npgtpo3dautoplugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/npgtpo3dautoplugin:  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/npgtpo3dautoplugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/npgtpo3dautoplugin, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/npgtpo3dautoplugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/npgtpo3dautoplugin: mach-o, but wrong architecture
2012-05-28 10:24:49.215 webkit_server[6274:207] Error loading /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Silverlight.plugin/Contents/MacOS/agcore:  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Silverlight.plugin/Contents/MacOS/agcore, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Silverlight.plugin/Contents/MacOS/agcore: mach-o, but wrong architecture
2012-05-28 10:24:49.262 webkit_server[6274:207] Error loading /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/googletalkbrowserplugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/googletalkbrowserplugin:  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/googletalkbrowserplugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/googletalkbrowserplugin, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/googletalkbrowserplugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/googletalkbrowserplugin: mach-o, but wrong architecture
2012-05-28 10:24:49.304 webkit_server[6274:207] Error loading /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin:  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/QuickTime Plugin.plugin/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Plugin: mach-o, but wrong architecture
2012-05-28 10:24:49.356 webkit_server[6274:207] Error loading /Users/Tyler/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Google Earth Web Plug-in.plugin/Contents/MacOS/libnpgeplugin.dylib:  dlopen(/Users/Tyler/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Google Earth Web Plug-in.plugin/Contents/MacOS/libnpgeplugin.dylib, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/Tyler/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Google Earth Web Plug-in.plugin/Contents/MacOS/libnpgeplugin.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
2012-05-28 10:24:49.454 webkit_server[6274:207] Error loading /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/net.juniper.DSSafariExtensions.plugin/Contents/MacOS/net.juniper.DSSafariExtensions:  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/net.juniper.DSSafariExtensions.plugin/Contents/MacOS/net.juniper.DSSafariExtensions, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/net.juniper.DSSafariExtensions.plugin/Contents/MacOS/net.juniper.DSSafariExtensions: mach-o, but wrong architecture
2012-05-28 10:24:49.823 webkit_server[6274:207] Error loading /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/SlingPlayer.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SlingPlayer:  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/SlingPlayer.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SlingPlayer, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/SlingPlayer.plugin/Contents/MacOS/SlingPlayer: mach-o, but wrong architecture
2012-05-28 10:24:49.887 webkit_server[6274:207] Error loading /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Unity Web Player.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Unity Web Player:  dlopen(/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Unity Web Player.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Unity Web Player, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Unity Web Player.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Unity Web Player: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

The weird thing is, if I run ALL the specs for my app, the first one (with the webkit driver) works. It's only the newer spec that throws this error.

Answer (score 1):

You may be hitting this known issue with loading webkit:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/157

Perhaps cleaning out your Internet Plug In directories will help?